# Ssrs Report - Section width

Tags: matrix, reporting-services

Could someone tell me please,why is section in ssrs report getting bigger? It is actually column transformed to row in matrix and until two values(second red row) is the width same as in design but from three values it s getting bigger although there is still space. Thanks a lot.

Report screenshot:

[image]

Design:
[Design picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cn5rM.jpg)

Comment: I think that as the matrix grows, it is pushing the edge of the object it's in. What does the design view look like? The design view might be more helpful. Is the your table in another rectangle that is in the gray rectangle? **Rectangles** are usually the answer to any formatting issue.

Comment: Yes, there are three tablixes. The top one is List with blue rectangle inside, inside is second List again with gray rectangle inside and in this one is red Matrix. Actually it is three level hierarchy and red matrix has actually row in columns perspective. I also tried to define max number of column in red matrix but till now I m not still sucessfull: ) I have attached design in original question.

Comment: Try putting your red table with **Name** (Tablix 5?) in a rectangle and close the edges so the rectangle is the same size. I think the rectangle will keep the tablix from pushing out the other edge.